# Identifying electronic components in Robotale Electronics fans package

Tags: components

I am trying to figure out what the following components.

1. Is the blue component to the left a potentiometer?
2. I would guess that the two black cylindrical objects are buzzers? Is there any way to identify how much voltage/current can be applied on it?
3. The LED like object, with four pins seems to be a LED that is a RGB led? Is that correct?

Below, I've included some pictures.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your assumptions are correct. Going from left to right and based on something I found describing that kit as including one active and one passive buzzer:

- That appears to be a potentiometer and the 103 marking will mean it's a 10K pot.
- That looks likes it would be the 'active' buzzer that includes a driver circuit because it's larger and includes a positive designator on the label. Unless it's marked and/or you can get a datasheet from the supplier I can't think of a good way to determine the voltage, but considering it's described as being useful with Arduinos I'd try applying 5 V and measure the current it uses to make sure it's not more than an I/O line can supply (if that's how you'll be using it).
- Yes that looks like an RGB LED. It might be a common cathode or anode and without a datasheet once again you'll probably have to do some testing but [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/71680/17064) about probing 7-segment displays could be applied to that as well.
- The last one I'd suspect is the 'passive' buzzer that will just be a piezo element without a driver. They need an AC driver of some sort and it's probably safest to use a transistor for those such as detailed in the question [Is this a proper way to connect a piezo speaker to MCU?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/39503/is-this-a-proper-way-to-connect-a-piezo-speaker-to-mcu)

So you'll have some experimentation to do and without datasheets and part numbers getting the exact specifications of components can be difficult to impossible.

While it can cost a little more sometimes while learning it can be less frustrating to start with components of a known origin and most of the more professional suppliers like Digikey and Element 14 are quite easy to deal with even for low volumes. Especially once you get a feel for the components that will be most useful to have on hand and you're ordering a few things at the same time to offset postage.